# Change letters in each word to make a new word

Tags: word

For each word in this list it is possible to change the first letter, then the second, then the third and then the fourth to make a new word each time.  The final words in each case are related and in alphabetical order. What are they?

> LAND, SLOT, SHIP, SHOW, WILD, KILT, ITEM, WHAM, CHOP, HAVE

*Source: The GCHQ Puzzle book*

Comment: Anush, these GCHQ puzzle book puzzles are good puzzles (of course) but I don't think it is proper to be posting so many of them here. At the rate you're going, soon the entire book will be on PSE, and the authors and publishers might reasonably object :-).

Comment: That is a very reasonable point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Helix for the inspiration;  go upvote their answer! They found that

> All of the final words are animals, in alphabetical order.

LAND

> BAND, BEND, BEAD, **BEAR** (thanks, @Helix!)

SLOT

> BLOT, BOOT, BOAT, **BOAR** (thanks, @Helix!)

SHIP

> CHIP, CLIP, CLAP, **CLAM** (thanks, @Omega Krypton!)

SHOW

> CHOW, CROW, CRAW, **CRAB**

WILD

> GILD, GOLD, GOAD, **GOAT**

KILT

> HILT, HALT, HART, **HARE**

ITEM

> STEM, SEEM, SEAM, **SEAL** (thanks, @Helix!)

WHAM

> SHAM, SLAM, SLUM, **SLUG**

CHOP

> SHOP, SWOP, SWAP, **SWAN** (or SHOP, STOP, STAP, **STAG**).

HAVE

> WAVE, WOVE, WORE, **WORM** (thanks, @Helix!)

Comment: Wow! Real Elite as your name suggests!

Comment: Haha you’re too funny! Thanks, @OmegaKrypton!

Comment: This is great although lots of people contributed to it I see. I didn't know some of the words like swop and stap.

Comment: It was definitely a team effort but credit was given where due. I believe both are English words though! How does this answer look, @Anush?

Answer (score 9):

They're related because...

> All of them are animals.

LAND

> BAND, BEND, BEAD, **BEAR**

SLOT

> BLOT, BOOT, BOAT, **BOAR**

SHIP

> CHIP, CLIP, CLAP, **CLAM** <sub>([Credits to Omega Krypton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72269/change-letters-in-each-word-to-make-a-new-word/72273#72273))</sub>

ITEM

> STEM, SEEM, SEAM, **SEAL**

HAVE

> WAVE, WOVE, WORE, **WORM**

Answer (score 2):

LAND

> BAND, BOND, BOLD, BOLT.

SLOT

> CLOT, COOT, COAT, COAL.

SHIP

> CHIP, CLIP, CLOP, CLOG.

Answer (score 1):

LAND:

> BAND, BOND, BOLD, BOLT. Credit to AHKieran

SLOT

> BLOT, BOOT, BOLT, BOLD.

SHIP

> CHIP, CLIP, CLAP, CLAM.

SHOW

> CHOW, CLOW, CLAW, CLAP.

HAVE

> WAVE, WOVE, WORE, WORN.

Comment: Thanks to helix, I know this is wrong. Please see my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

They're related because...

> All of them are animals. （Credits to Helix)

LAND

> BAND, BEND, BEAD, **BEAR** （Credits to Helix)

SLOT

> BLOT, BOOT, BOAT, **BOAR** （Credits to Helix)

SHIP

> CHIP, CLIP, CLAP, **CLAM**

SHOW

> CHOW, CROW, CRAW, **CRAB**

ITEM

> STEM, SEEM, SEAM, **SEAL** （Credits to Helix)

HAVE

> WAVE, WOVE, WORE, **WORM** （Credits to Helix)